# How to implement left join on data range in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to convert the below oracle logic to hive.
Logic:

```
Select a.id,a.name,b.desc from table a left join table b on
a.num between b.min_num and b.max_num;
```

Could any one help me out to achieve the above logic in hive.

Comment: You can't do it. MR cannot support anything for outer joins other than an equi-join. If you have anything else to join on, you can try move the range piece to your where clause and play with null testing.

Comment: @Andrew - I can think of at least 2 ways to do it

Answer (score 1):

With this solution you have the control on the performance.
`b` ranges are being split to sub-ranges, small as you want (`x`).

- Too big `x` will practically cause a CROSS JOIN.
- Too small `x` might generate a huge set from `b` (`x`=1 will generate all `b` ranges' values).

---

```
set hivevar:x=100;

select  a.id
       ,a.name
       ,b.desc

from        table_a as a 

        left join  

            (select  a.id
                   ,b.desc

            from        table_a as a

                    inner join 

                       (select   b.min_num div ${hivevar:x} + pe.pos    as sub_range_id
                                ,b.*

                        from        table_b as b
                                lateral view 
                                    posexplode(split(space(cast (b.max_num div ${hivevar:x} - b.min_num div ${hivevar:x} as int)),' ')) pe
                        ) as b

                    on          a.num div ${hivevar:x}  =
                                b.sub_range_id

            where   a.num between b.min_num and b.max_num
            ) b                    

        on          b.id   =
                    a.id
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the 3rd solution @Dude. It can be more helpful to optimze the hql performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  a.id
       ,a.name
       ,b.desc

from                table_a as a 

        left join  (select  a.id
                           ,b.desc

                    from                table_a as a
                            cross join  table_b as b

                    where   a.num between b.min_num and b.max_num
                    ) b                    

        on          b.id   =
                    a.id
;
```

Comment: Yes,  a cross join would work, but that doesn't make it a good idea.  You're also assuming the OP has some sort of ID to work with, but the original query doesn't show that.

Comment: @Andrew - **(1)** CROSS JOIN is an option, good or not, it depends on the data demographics. **(2)** You assume that `a.id` is not an ID for `a`?

Comment: Thanks for solution @dude Markovitz. a.id is key field for table a. How about query performance if I have 1m records in table a and 1k records in table b.

Comment: @ssk, not amazing. The other solution might do the work, depends on the min-max values of `b`. **P.s.** a 3rd solution is on is way :-)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - I am not assuming anything about table A, but I am also not assuming table B even has an ID column to join on.  Hopefully it does though.

Comment: @Andrew, the `id` I'm using is `a`'s not `b`'s

Answer (score 0):

```
select  a.id
       ,a.name
       ,b.desc

from                table_a as a 

        left join  (select  b.min_num + pe.pos  as num
                           ,b.desc

                    from    table_b as b
                                lateral view 
                                    posexplode(split(space(b.max_num-b.min_num),' ')) pe
                    ) b                    

        on          b.num   =
                    a.num
;
```

Comment: @DudeMarkovitz, I am exactly not sure about the above logic, can you pls describe logic if possible. Thanks in advance for third solution.

Comment: @ssk, It creates the values within each `[min_num,max_num]` range. E.g. for `min_num`=7 and `max_num`=11, 5 records will be created with the values 7,8,9,10 and 11.